# How do I properly store an array of dates from React Multi Date Picker

Tags: reactjs, forms, npm, datepicker

I'm creating a form that needs the user to select multiple days, not in a range. I'm trying to implement the [multi-date-picker](https://shahabyazdi.github.io/react-multi-date-picker/multiple/)  but anything I've tried has returned undefined.

I very new so assume I'm missing something basic here, any help on how this should be set up is appreciated.

```
  const {
    date
  } = useAppContext()


  const[values,setValue] =  React.useState([]);

  const handleDates = (value) =>{
    const name = 'date'
    setValue({...values, value})
    handleChange({ name, values })
  }

    <DatePicker 
          multiple
          value={values}
          name= "date" 
          onChange={handleDates}
          minDate="2023/02/16"
          maxDate="2023/02/26"   
          
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you define `value` as an array `[]`:

`const[values,setValue] =  React.useState([]);`

However, you change it into an object here:

`setValue({...values, value}); // destructured object`

This should be:

`setValue([...values, value]); //<--- destructured array`